# What is the difference between NULL and \N while loading data from a csv using load data local infile

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, load

I have a table which has four fields

```
create table test_hc1(cola int,colb int,colc varchar(20),cold int);
```

Now, I am trying to load following data

```
1,2,\N,4
```

and the third field in table is coming out as NULL, which is the expected result.

In another case, I am trying to load following data

```
1,2,NULL,4
```

and it is also loading the third field as NULL.

Here is my question : What is the difference between using the two(\N, NULL) ?

I am using

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'PATH_TO_DATAFILE'
INTO TABLE TABLE_NAME FIELDS TERMINATED BY x'01';
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your options `FIELDS` and `LINES` used in the `LOAD DATA` statement.

[MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html)

## From MySQL doc:

> Handling of NULL values varies according to the FIELDS and LINES
>   options in use:
>
> For the default FIELDS and LINES values, NULL is written as a field
>   value of \N for output, and a field value of \N is read as NULL for
>   input (assuming that the ESCAPED BY character is “\”).
>
> If FIELDS ENCLOSED BY is not empty, a field containing the literal
>   word NULL as its value is read as a NULL value. This differs from the
>   word NULL enclosed within FIELDS ENCLOSED BY characters, which is read
>   as the string 'NULL'.
>
> If FIELDS ESCAPED BY is empty, NULL is written as the word NULL.
>
> With fixed-row format (which is used when FIELDS TERMINATED BY and
>   FIELDS ENCLOSED BY are both empty), NULL is written as an empty
>   string. Note that this causes both NULL values and empty strings in
>   the table to be indistinguishable when written to the file because
>   both are written as empty strings. If you need to be able to tell the
>   two apart when reading the file back in, you should not use fixed-row
>   format.

Answer (score 0):

From the MySQL documentation:

The NULL value means “no data.” NULL can be written in any lettercase. A synonym is \N (case sensitive).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/null-values.html